# Show total progress on rsync

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, file-transfer, rsync

I'm trying to get Rsync to show total progress of the job using

```
rsync -a -v -h -i --partial -r --no-inc-recursive --info=progress2  alex@RemoteLocation LocalLocation
```

But I think it doesn't explore and compare all the files to be able to determine what files need to be replaced and how long it'll take.

It just starts copying files. Looks like this in the terminal:

```
>f+++++++++ Simpsons [cz]/aaa.mkv
          1.64G   0%  439.17kB/s 3408:32:25
```

But there's only little bit of data to be copied but it is calculating the time as if it was copying everything, not only changed or extra files as it should with the -a option

Comment: If you ran this command it wouldn't copy from a remote location, but instead it would attempt to copy from a local file/directory called `alex@RemoteLocation`. Perhaps you meant `rsync -avihP --no-i-r alex@RemoteLocation: LocalLocation`

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done unfortunately. `rsync` doesn't even walk the entire source tree for large trees before it starts transferring, so it has no idea what the total is.

Comment: My understanding was that it can with the options -r (recursive) and -no-inc-recursive (no incremental recursion). This way it should go down the directory tree and see all the files to calculate the total remaining.